# Remove duplicates from panda dataframe but keep the row if it repeats after another set

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove the duplicates and keep first but I also want to keep the row if the set repeats again -

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

dfa = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
    Date/Time         C_1    C_2
"16/08/2023 3:00:15" online offline
"16/08/2023 3:00:17" online offline
"16/08/2023 3:00:18" offline online
"16/08/2023 3:00:21" offline online
"16/08/2023 3:00:24" offline online
"16/08/2023 3:00:23" offline online
"16/08/2023 3:00:26" offline online
"16/08/2023 3:00:28" online offline
"16/08/2023 3:00:31" online offline
"16/08/2023 3:00:37" online offline
"16/08/2023 3:00:39" online offline
"16/08/2023 3:00:42" online offline"""), sep="\s+")
dfa = dfa.drop_duplicates(['C_1','C_2']).reset_index(drop=True)
print(dfa)
```

Output I am geeting is -

```
    Date/Time        C_1    C_2
16/08/2023 3:00:15  online  offline
16/08/2023 3:00:18  offline online
```

But I am expecting -

```
   Date/Time         C_1    C_2
16/08/2023 3:00:15 online offline
16/08/2023 3:00:18 offline online
16/08/2023 3:00:28 online offline
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us create a intermediate group column to identify different blocks having same set values, then use this new column along with set columns to drop dupes

```
c = ['C_1', 'C_2']
dfa['grps'] = dfa[c].ne(dfa[c].shift()).any(1).cumsum()

dfa.drop_duplicates([*c, 'grps'])
```

---

```
            Date/Time      C_1      C_2  grps
0  16/08/2023 3:00:15   online  offline     1
2  16/08/2023 3:00:18  offline   online     2
7  16/08/2023 3:00:28   online  offline     3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can test if not equal shifted values by [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) and [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
out = dfa[dfa[['C_1', 'C_2']].ne(dfa[['C_1', 'C_2']].shift()).any(axis=1)]
print (out)
            Date/Time      C_1      C_2
0  16/08/2023 3:00:15   online  offline
2  16/08/2023 3:00:18  offline   online
7  16/08/2023 3:00:28   online  offline
```

Answer (score 2):

**Example**

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

dfa = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
    Date/Time         C_1    C_2
"16/08/2023 3:00:15" online offline
"16/08/2023 3:00:17" online offline
"16/08/2023 3:00:18" offline online
"16/08/2023 3:00:21" offline online
"16/08/2023 3:00:24" offline online
"16/08/2023 3:00:23" offline online
"16/08/2023 3:00:26" offline online
"16/08/2023 3:00:28" online offline
"16/08/2023 3:00:31" online offline
"16/08/2023 3:00:37" online offline
"16/08/2023 3:00:39" online offline
"16/08/2023 3:00:42" online offline"""), sep="\s+")
```

**Code**

```
df = dfa[['C_1', 'C_2']]
cond = df.eq(df.shift()).all(axis=1)
dfa[~cond]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Create a mask to identify rows where the set repeats
mask = (dfa['C_1'] != dfa['C_1'].shift()) | (dfa['C_2'] != dfa['C_2'].shift())
# Apply the mask to keep the rows where the set repeats
result = dfa[mask]
# Reset the index if needed
result = result.reset_index(drop=True)
```